# Geometry Nodes: Face Corner Colors

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-colors

'Vertex' painting is actually face-corner painting. So per-face colors are possible, can be picked up by an *Attribute* input node in shader-trees.

Here are 2 color-attribute layers on a cube, both registered as **Face Corner > Color** in its 'Data' tab  > 'Color Attributes' panel.

`pcol` has been painted, per face. That's successfully interpreted by the shader:

[image]

`col` has been generated and captured, per face, in a GN tree:

[image]

The spreadsheet shows that face-corners have independent colors, per-face..

And yet this time, the colors are interpolated across vertices by the shader.

[image]

.. in the latest 3.2b, at posting time.

Have I just made a silly slip, or are we waiting for further development?

Comment: The silly slip is that the Viewer doesn't show the output of the group, remove the viewer and now you can look at the output - with the `pcol` being only on the point domain. :)

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady  That's 2 silly slips! Every now and then, it's good to be taken back to when I started using Blender, and tore what little remained of my hair out with frustration :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to change attribute domain to face corner:

[image]

Attribute saved in this domain, if you capture attribute from faces and put it into vertex - they will be converted from face to vertices, leading to unexpected result.

Face corner domain:

[image]

Face domain:

[image]

Comment: Hi Crantisz! Thanks! .. but I would expect per-face colors, as shown in the spreadsheet, just the same as you get with 'vertex' painting? The reason for capturing on the Face domain is to get the same random color in all corners of a face.

Comment: Yep, If you set faces as a domain

Comment: No, it's not here! It is in properties panel inside Geometry Nodes editor *Group* tab